# how to aggregate with multifunction for different columns with one of the functions is mode function

Tags: python, group-by, aggregate-functions, mode

```
dfwb = dfwb.groupby(['WELL','YEAR','MONTH'])[['GOR','PSI']].agg({'GOR':'mean', 'PSI': pd.Series.mode[0]})
```

how to aggregate with multifunction for different columns with one of the functions is mode function. I've tried this following code but it result an error:

'function' object is not subscriptable

anyone know how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: You probably need to define a lambda function, as Python doesn't know what you mean by the first element of a callable.  Something like
`lambda s: s.mode[0]` rather than `pd.Series.mode[0]`

Comment: @Shffl so itu should be lke this .....agg({'GOR':'mean', 'PSI': lambda s: s.mode[0]}) ?

Comment: @sagi the what is the correct one? I only want to groupby using mode function for one specified column

Comment: Looking at what I wrote before, it should be `s.mode()[0]`, but otherwise, yes, that should work

Comment: @Shffl wow thanks a lot bro, it gives me the right result